# Fatal Error when trying to load Permalinks page on WP admin

Tags: permalinks, wp-admin, errors, fatal-error

I'm receiving the below error when trying to access the Permalinks section on the WP admin. The page does not load and shows the error message instead. I cannot understand what this means or what has to be done. Any ideas are appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
 apache_get_modules() in
 /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:5283
 Stack trace: #0
 /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/misc.php(17):
 apache_mod_loaded('mod_rewrite', true) #1
 /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/misc.php(46):
 got_mod_rewrite() #2
 /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-admin/options-permalink.php(71):
 got_url_rewrite() #3 {main} thrown in
 /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php
 on line 5283
```

Comment: I downgraded the php version to 7.2 which removed this error on my Siteground Hosting.

Comment: You need to contact your hosting provider, this shouldn't happen unless you're using a super old version of WP ( the fix for this was made 13+ years ago ), either that or the apache module is not installed correctly on the server

Comment: It must be the apache module then as I'm running the latest Wordpress 5.5.1 on PHP 7.3.20. I now downgraded to 7.2.32 and the permalinks page is now showing again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is related with the Hosting Server PHP Version. So if you are on PHP 7.3.XX try downgrading to 7.2.xx or 7.1.xx and see if that helps!

P.S. I was facing the same issue and had to downgrade to PHP 7.1 to fix it!

Comment: Thank you Sheryl. This worked when I downgraded to 7.2.32